# Stored procedure call problem in Powerbuilder10 on Windows 10 64bit

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I get this error message when the DW calls the stored procedure with several parameters:

> DW error event occur
>   Select Error. An error occurred, yet no message was returned by the database driver. sqldbcode 999

The DB was connected as like this:

- SQLCA.DBMS = "ODBC"
- SQLCA.AutoCommit = False
- SQLCA.DBParm = "ConnectString='DSN=XXX_prod;UID=aaa;PWD=xxxx'" + "StripParmNames='YES' and CallEscape='No'"

Connect using sqlca;

The "XXX_prod" is the 32bit ODBC Data Source DSN for SQL Server.

Before, it was "OLE DB" on Windows 7, but, on Windows 10, I have to change the to use ODBC.

From this time, this error occurred:

> "DW error event occur",
>   "Select Error. An error occurred, yet no message was returned by the database driver. sqldbcode 999")

This is the procedure `aaa.sp_dw_xxx` being called by the DW

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [aaa].[sp_dw_xxx] 
    (@as_st_ym varchar(8), 
     @as_yymmdd varchar(8), 
     @as_yymmdd2 varchar(8), 
     @as_model varchar(20), 
     @as_pn varchar(20), 
     @as_brand varchar(20) ,
     @as_product varchar(20) ='%')
AS
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

    SELECT 
    FROM   
    WHERE
```

This is the code of the exported DW source:

```
.
.
procedure="1 execute aaa.sp_dw_xxx;1 @as_st_ym = :as_st_ym,  @as_yymmdd = :as_yymm, @as_yymmdd2 = :as_yymm2, @as_model=:as_model, @as_pn = :as_pn,@as_brand = :as_brand ,@as_product = :as_product" arguments = (("as_st_ym", string),("as_yymm", string), ("as_yymm2", string),("as_model", string), ("as_pn", string), ("as_brand", string),("as_product", string)))
.
```

Comment: Not really related to the question, but you shouldn't name your procedures "sp_", it has a special meaning. And SQL Server 2008 has passed it's end of life already.

Comment: Generally, every procedure should have "set nocount on" as the first statement. "Read Uncommitted"? Do you really, REALLY understand what this does, the errors it can generate, the incorrect information it can return? Sending dates as strings? Using 2 digit years? And obsolete/unsupported tools - I see all kinds of problems waiting for you.